# Why doesn't Devtools respect my dependency constraints in an R package

Tags: r, package, devops, versioning, devtools

I am not an R programmer. I am a web developer that is used to composer dependency manager for PHP which has .json file that lets you specify package version constraints for your application. Then you run the manager and it resolves your dependencies to a set of versions, which it writes in the .lock file. From that lock file I have a very specific set of package version that does not change when I deploy to my production environment.

I am looking for similar mechanics with R as we are running R in the cloud and we are looking to automate the deployment and we want to be sure we have the exact same package version running in dev as in production.

So to get a similar behavior, I've decided to lock the dependencies in the DESCRIPTION file of my package by specifying an exact version of my package (which not recommended in the docs). So I've made an empty R package with a single dependency (by following this tutorial: https://tinyheero.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/07/26/making-your-first-R-package.html) with the following DESCRIPTION. ananas is just a random name for my random package.

```
Package: ananas
Title: What the Package Does (One Line, Title Case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: 
    person(given = "First",
           family = "Last",
           role = c("aut", "cre"),
           email = "first.last@example.com",
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
License: What license it uses
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports:
    anytime (== 0.3.0)
```

If you check the documentation at http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#dependencies and you scroll to "versioning" title (not "version" which is further down). You can see an example clearly stating that it is possible to use exact dependencies version constraints.

Then I tried to use the following commands to install the dependencies and the package itself

```
Rscript -e 'devtools::install("ananas", lib="r-library", upgrade="never")'
Rscript -e 'devtools::install("ananas", lib="r-library")'
```

And I have an .Rprofile file located where I run the install command with the following content

```
.libPaths(c("./r-library", .libPaths()))
```

Yet, when I got to the r-library folder to check the package `anytime`. I opened the DESCRIPTION file for the `anytime` package and I see it is at the latest version of 0.3.7 at the time of writing this which does not correspond to the constraints of exactly 0.3.0 in the DESCRIPTION file of my package.

So my question is why devtools does not respect the version constraints? What am I missing?

Very similar to the following unanswered stackoverflow issue: [R doesn't respect maximum version when installing package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684736/r-doesnt-respect-maximum-version-when-installing-package-dependencies)

Comment: Did you try removing the `==`? I think I once had the reverse problem where I forgot to type `>=` and my package complained because my library had a higher version of the dependency.

Comment: You may also find the renv package to be helpful: https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html